# Writing a mod security rule to block access to a PHP file

Tags: mod-security

I wish to block access to any file with name "modules.php" in any website.
I have written a Rule in mod security but I'm not sure if it is working or not?
here is the rule

```
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "@rx modules.php" \
"phase:2,block,severity:2,msg:'Blocking access to modules.php files.'"
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Instead REQUEST_LINE to REQUEST_FILE for better performance.